# Java app deployment to heroku using Maven failed

Tags: java, heroku, continuous-integration, maven-3, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup the Continuous deployment process for a Tomcat based java app using Github for source code hosting, TravisCI for building the WAR file, running the unit tests and then Heroku to deploy the packaged WAR file.

**I tried following the tutorial from**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-war-files-to-heroku-from-travis-ci#creating-a-java-web-application

**I am getting an error while running the below step from the above tutorial:**

mvn clean heroku:deploy-war

**Command outpt:**

```
$ mvn -e clean heroku:deploy-war
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:travis-heroku-java-example:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 31, column 10
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Web Application 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [travis-heroku-java-example] in [/home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/travis-heroku-java-example]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [86 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/travis-heroku-java-example.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:7.0.57.2:jar
[INFO] Copying webapp-runner-7.0.57.2.jar to /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
[INFO] ---> Packaging application...
[INFO]      - app: possessed-cemetery-7933
[INFO]      - including: target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
[INFO]      - including: target/travis-heroku-java-example.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.636s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 24 03:33:35 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[**ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) on project travis-heroku-java-example: Failed to deploy application: Forbidden -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) on project travis-heroku-java-example: Failed to deploy application**
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to deploy application
        at com.heroku.sdk.maven.DeployWarMojo.execute(DeployWarMojo.java:24)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.RestClient.handleResponse(RestClient.java:87)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:26)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.ConfigVars.getConfigVars(ConfigVars.java:39)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.ConfigVars.merge(ConfigVars.java:22)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.mergeConfigVars(App.java:152)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:81)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:87)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.WarApp.deploy(WarApp.java:29)
        at com.heroku.sdk.maven.DeployWarMojo.execute(DeployWarMojo.java:20)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
$
```

**Error Message in the above output:**

```
[**ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) on project travis-heroku-java-example: Failed to deploy application: Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

**Here is the Maven System configuration:**

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-79-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Java Version is:**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
$
```

**Pom file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>travis-heroku-java-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Simple Web Application</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.4_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>rubygems-releases</id>
      <url>http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <finalName>travis-heroku-java-example</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <appName>possessed-cemetery-7933</appName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.3.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <appName>boiling-beach-1111</appName>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
          <configuration>
            <execArgLines>
              <execArgLine>${project.build.directory}/rubygems/bin/travis</execArgLine>
              <execArgLine>encrypt</execArgLine>
              <execArgLine>HEROKU_API_KEY=${herokuApiKey}</execArgLine>
            </execArgLines>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>rubygems</groupId>
              <artifactId>travis</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.1</version>
              <type>gem</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>rubygems</groupId>
              <artifactId>pry</artifactId>
              <version>0.9.12.6</version>
              <type>gem</type>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden` - looks like you're not authenticating.  See the first part of [the guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-war-files-to-heroku-from-travis-ci#deploying-to-heroku-from-travis).

Comment: @SteveChaloner Hi Steve, thanks for looking into it. I think that the authentication part needs to be considered when the app is being deployed from TravisCI to Heroku. I havent gotten that far in the guide yet. I am stuck at the step where the Maven will deploy the war to the heroku using heroku's maven plugin "heroku:deploy-war". I ran that command from the ubuntu terminal where in the Heroku authenticates the deployment from the credentials provided at the command line.

Comment: What happens if you use the heroku toolbelt to check your current status?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that :( . Do you?

Comment: [https://toolbelt.heroku.com/](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)

Comment: Oops. I have been using the tool belt for some time now. I meant to ask you as to how to check the status using the toolbelt.

Comment: ´heroku help´ will show you available commands. ´heroku status´ shows the state of the Heroku platform, ´heroku logs´ will pull down the logs for your app - this is an easy way to check you're authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the issue was!!!

Heroku deploy-war maven plugin requires Maven 3.2.X version while I was using 3.0.X version.

Installed Maven 3.2.1 version on my ubuntu machine and the war file was successfully deployed to Heroku.

I got to know this from Github Heroku Maven plugin repository Readme file:

```
Requirements

Maven 3.2.x
Java 1.7 or higher
```

Thank you @Steve for your time.

Output:

```
$ maven -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T17:37:52+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-79-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
$
$
$
$ maven -e clean heroku:deploy-war
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:travis-heroku-java-example:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 31, column 11
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Web Application 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [travis-heroku-java-example] in [/home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/travis-heroku-java-example]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [38 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/travis-heroku-java-example.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.6:deploy-war (default-cli) @ travis-heroku-java-example ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:7.0.57.2:jar
[INFO] Copying webapp-runner-7.0.57.2.jar to /home/ciuser/travis-heroku-java-example/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
[INFO] ---> Packaging application...
[INFO]      - app: boiling-beach-1111
[INFO]      - including: target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
[INFO]      - including: target/travis-heroku-java-example.war
[INFO]      - installing: OpenJDK 1.8
[INFO] ---> Creating slug...
[INFO]      - file: target/heroku/slug.tgz
[INFO]      - size: 56MB
[INFO] ---> Uploading slug...
[INFO]      - stack: cedar-14
[INFO]      - process types: [web]
[INFO] ---> Releasing...
[INFO]      - version: 6
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 32.265 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-24T20:05:46+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```